# Angular 2 Forms . Passing data from one component to another with a text box on clicking of a button

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am a beginner to angular 2 . I want a data to be typed in a textbox which on entering (say on click of enter button ) i need the data to be taken to another component where i can append the data to another variable . How do i do this ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: By  **Another component** you want to share during routing or another child component of the parent

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should have nested components, lets say a child component which is firing an event to the parent component when the Enter-Button is pressed. With the ()-Binding you can register to that event in the parent component and reading the value given with a parameter.

```
<form>
 // your form...
    <button type="submit" (click)="clickButton();>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and in your ts:

```
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output() buttonWasClicked = new EventEmitter<string>();

    public clickButton = (): void => {
        this.buttonWasClicked.emit(this.myValueToPass);
    }
}
```

In your parent component you are using the child component like this:

```
<child-component (buttonWasClicked)="makeSomething($event)"></child-component>

export class ParentComponent {

    public makeSomething(valueWhichWasPassed: string) {
        // Make Something with value
    }
}
```

This is pseudo code I typed in here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use App.component,

App.component

```html
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h2> Hello </h2>`,
})

export class AppComponent {
  @Input() textBoxValue: string = ''
}
```

In component 1 write the below code

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './appComponent'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModal)]="textboxValue"/>
      <button type="button" (click)="onEntered()"> Enter   </button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Component1{
  textboxValue: string = '';

  constructor(private appComponent:AppComponent){

  }

  onEntered(): void{
    this.appComponent.textBoxValue = this.textboxValue;
  }

}
```

In component 2 take the value from AppComponent

```html
value: string = this.appComponent.textBoxValue;
```